# Find rest height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment

I have sidemenu which is contain logo and category wrap. Сategory wrap is located in the middle of sidemu. I need to find the height between category wrap and top of sidemenu - and then I could put my logo in the middle of that land.

Tried this:

```
var catHeight = $('.cat-wrap').height(),
    sidemenuHeight = $('.sidemenu').height();

  var  x = $('#logo-sidemenu').css('height','calc( 'sidemenuHeight - catHeight / 2'  )' + 'px');
  $('#logo-sidemenu').height(x);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt4gL/1/)

Comment: Your x is not set to the height, `$('#logo-sidemenu').css('height','calc( 'sidemenuHeight - catHeight / 2'  )' + 'px')` does not return an integer. In your fiddle the sidemenu height var is also wrong(typo)

Comment: Your height calc produces the number -140.5 which is not a valid value for height. See http://jsfiddle.net/Tt4gL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
// doc.ready shorthand
    $(function() {
      var catHeight = $('.cat-wrap').height();
      var sidemenuHeight = $('#sidemenu').height();
      var theHeight = (sidemenuHeight - catHeight) / 2;
      $('#logo-sidemenu').height(theHeight);
    });
```

The jQuery `height()` function takes an integer value, not another jQuery object which is what you were trying to do.

For sidemenu, you were targeting a class, not an ID which is what that element has.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tt4gL/5/